# Morris.js charts not working for me

Tags: jquery, html, charts, morris.js

Any help
Using morris.js charts. Downloaded from here

https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/

All works well, however when I want to add a different type of chart the chart will not show up, and he donut chart below stops working.

I want to change the type of chart on a page, so I add the code, then in the html I change the div id

Here is the .js

```
 // First Chart Example - Area Line Chart
Morris.Area({
// ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
element: 'morris-chart-area',
// Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
// the chart.
data: [
{ d: '2012-10-01', visits: 802 },
{ d: '2012-10-02', visits: 783 },
{ d: '2012-10-03', visits:  820 },
{ d: '2012-10-04', visits: 839 },
{ d: '2012-10-05', visits: 792 },
{ d: '2012-10-06', visits: 859 },
{ d: '2012-10-07', visits: 790 },
{ d: '2012-10-08', visits: 1680 },
{ d: '2012-10-09', visits: 1592 },
{ d: '2012-10-10', visits: 1420 },
{ d: '2012-10-11', visits: 882 },
{ d: '2012-10-12', visits: 889 },
{ d: '2012-10-13', visits: 819 },
{ d: '2012-10-14', visits: 849 },
{ d: '2012-10-15', visits: 870 },
{ d: '2012-10-16', visits: 1063 },
{ d: '2012-10-17', visits: 1192 },
{ d: '2012-10-18', visits: 1224 },
{ d: '2012-10-19', visits: 1329 },
{ d: '2012-10-20', visits: 1329 },
{ d: '2012-10-21', visits: 1239 },
{ d: '2012-10-22', visits: 1190 },
{ d: '2012-10-23', visits: 1312 },
{ d: '2012-10-24', visits: 1293 },
{ d: '2012-10-25', visits: 1283 },
{ d: '2012-10-26', visits: 1248 },
{ d: '2012-10-27', visits: 1323 },
{ d: '2012-10-28', visits: 1390 },
{ d: '2012-10-29', visits: 1420 },
{ d: '2012-10-30', visits: 1529 },
{ d: '2012-10-31', visits: 1892 },
],
// The name of the data record attribute that contains x-visitss.
xkey: 'd',
// A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-visitss.
 ykeys: ['visits'],
 // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
// chart.
labels: ['Visits'],
// Disables line smoothing
smooth: false,
});

Morris.Donut({
element: 'morris-chart-donut',
 data: [
{label: "Bounce", value: 42.7},
{label: "Engagment", value: 57.3},

],
formatter: function (y) { return y + "%" ;}
});

Morris.Line({
// ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
element: 'morris-chart-line',
// Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
// the chart.
data: [
{ d: '2012-10-01', visits: 802 },
{ d: '2012-10-02', visits: 783 },
{ d: '2012-10-03', visits:  820 },
{ d: '2012-10-04', visits: 839 },
{ d: '2012-10-05', visits: 792 },
{ d: '2012-10-06', visits: 859 },
{ d: '2012-10-07', visits: 790 },
{ d: '2012-10-08', visits: 1680 },
{ d: '2012-10-09', visits: 1592 },
{ d: '2012-10-10', visits: 1420 },
{ d: '2012-10-11', visits: 882 },
{ d: '2012-10-12', visits: 889 },
{ d: '2012-10-13', visits: 819 },
{ d: '2012-10-14', visits: 849 },
{ d: '2012-10-15', visits: 870 },
{ d: '2012-10-16', visits: 1063 },
{ d: '2012-10-17', visits: 1192 },
{ d: '2012-10-18', visits: 1224 },
{ d: '2012-10-19', visits: 1329 },
{ d: '2012-10-20', visits: 1329 },
{ d: '2012-10-21', visits: 1239 },
{ d: '2012-10-22', visits: 1190 },
{ d: '2012-10-23', visits: 1312 },
{ d: '2012-10-24', visits: 1293 },
{ d: '2012-10-25', visits: 1283 },
{ d: '2012-10-26', visits: 1248 },
{ d: '2012-10-27', visits: 1323 },
{ d: '2012-10-28', visits: 1390 },
{ d: '2012-10-29', visits: 1420 },
{ d: '2012-10-30', visits: 1529 },
{ d: '2012-10-31', visits: 1892 },
],
// The name of the data record attribute that contains x-visitss.
xkey: 'd',
// A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-visitss.
ykeys: ['visits'],
// Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
// chart.
labels: ['Visits'],
// Disables line smoothing
smooth: false,
});

Morris.Bar ({
element: 'morris-chart-bar',
data: [
{device: 'iPhone', geekbench: 136},
{device: 'iPhone 3G', geekbench: 137},
{device: 'iPhone 3GS', geekbench: 275},
{device: 'iPhone 4', geekbench: 380},
{device: 'iPhone 4S', geekbench: 655},
{device: 'iPhone 5', geekbench: 1571}
],
xkey: 'device',
ykeys: ['geekbench'],
labels: ['Geekbench'],
barRatio: 0.4,
xLabelAngle: 35,
hideHover: 'auto'
});

// Use Morris.Area instead of Morris.Line
Morris.Area({
element: 'graph',
data: [
{x: '2010 Q4', y: 3, z: 7},
{x: '2011 Q1', y: 3, z: 4},
{x: '2011 Q2', y: null, z: 1},
{x: '2011 Q3', y: 2, z: 5},
{x: '2011 Q4', y: 8, z: 2},
{x: '2012 Q1', y: 4, z: 4}
],
xkey: 'x',
ykeys: ['y', 'z'],
labels: ['Y', 'Z']
}).on('click', function(i, row){
console.log(i, row);
});

    // Use Morris.Bar
Morris.Bar({
element: 'graph',
data:  [
{x: '2011 Q1', y: 3, z: 2, a: 3},
{x: '2011 Q2', y: 2, z: null, a: 1},
{x: '2011 Q3', y: 0, z: 2, a: 4},
{x: '2011 Q4', y: 2, z: 4, a: 3}
],
xkey: 'x',
ykeys: ['y', 'z', 'a'],
labels: ['Y', 'Z', 'A'],
stacked: true
});
```

and here is my HTML section

```
  <!-- start of bars chart-->
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Store     Optiisation: October 1, 2013 - October 31, 2013</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="morris-chart-graph"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the donut section

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> Traffic Sources: October 1, 2013 - October 31, 2013</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="morris-chart-donut"></div>
            <div class="text-right">
              <a href="#">View Details <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Any help be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the function in js file works in order, you should do couple of things and same code will start working for you. 
1. you should make a copy of downloaded script and current working file
2. then you need to edit js file as per you page, means if you are using that javascript file with your index page to show graphs/charts then you need to make a copy only for index and only those charts will be available on the page which you are using on index.

for example if you are using only using donut and bar-chart then only use these charts in file and specially use them in order. if you want to place bar chart first in you html then first code will be bar chart in js file and then donut.....you can have other chart javascript codes after them, but if you have any other chart before them which you are not using that will create problem and you will not able to see on html.

i hope you able to see your charts.